# How to perform select->cut/copy->paste/move the selected area in android finger paint?

Tags: android, android-canvas, paint

am developing painting app. i want to select the painted area and cut, move / paste the same like doing in this app [link1](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.acadoid.lecturenotestrial),[link2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tecxten.andropaint.free). I am using finger paint app in api demo. I don't know how to do this. Anybody know please help me Thank you.